# How to show X-axis label for the only points where data is available?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am plotting a time graph with echarts. I have only two data points I want to show in the graph. The graph shows those two points correctly, but it shows more than 2 labels on x axis (time axis), which is obviously the uniform time difference between those 2 data points. What I want is to see the time labels only for the data points I have. How can I do that?

I tried passing the time values in `xAxis.data` also, but it is not working.

I have created a demo graph for reference [here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeBYAULTsBOBTAziDPhAG64BcsY2ArrgDTpbXDAA2kIVqGL12CAHMhubFQBEAQwAeEfBKZ8W-ABbAA7lRr0l_arhlgAymACe7Ssmb7YAMxgmIALysBGAEx7-AX2-Y_G0wwNnYAI2AZHiCsQSFVMCo3ADZ_LDtcKTBaPGjlfgBbKWwAazzbLDVNbTpGGJZA_JYioQgAYwAVMxArXgrMKq17KXZ8OqasRoq8fBDc6wmVdSGdcYqp3zSNzAATLKkALTYC8v5zHskIaBId3EUY7dghQR3TljbHKSuAGSkw3HYNV0DzSpHktBGAFkpNxYABtAC6aUsomgrwW-nOVgk-Da2A47HuExGwmgkksdjARP0EDAuAKAAlcMIEkkAAxpTC0-kAdQgOzAqnZnIMRlMFl69XSjmMLncHKlj0eMgAgnJ8G9KssgWszt1sZACncRXswFIqIiRdApEbJB0IEbqfxrUbvsA2lkoGTYBICvydpYnSwXbgOoYTOZLJqWA5oE5XEkACwizCxsA85nxRI-iLsW7YIP8cjYSAe9gq9ikyQhECFlggKQ7HZXIQWgDMqVgHK7DC7SMVVptuAA4jCqAriZWhNB7W0ShqBMDierfv9ARjbPizXTJHWsMBi3Z2NUfTpoB66XvMKp-bgAPLF9hj4ajXX6QbQmSrgE6lOwD8_H8P6Lm-_BprKCawG4yZSqmwDYEUYB0uIPpIGY6FmD4AC0SCQpC2FIE2PgADrQEgqiqD4FBIAUBRUUg-D4D4Poio8mCyPIs5lBu77aiBf4ktOfKCt-66rKxIoRLQaLFGYo6wuJIIxGYaryBaUp9LYWKSKQIz0FesAhruAlTjO7Tzr-sGwEQJCQDA5K4JSBkcfgonRvwN63A-YhPrCdgjGMf4DMsn5ufxVnBZokKAWulmLNKcYQe4XhWWxWAud8VySvFkUrLUQWwEU2CtN6E79LAlbQLg4pRjxthpSwMAHGIwBUP5r5_g1_4gJWYAAHK0AU_woRIBkhm6F5epIuBomNQ5hmKkbZeV4FykkKU5fYjgZiy2YSLm-YGWljz9vkYyCAQ6kTJp-imua8IRfCKQAKyJmyADsz0ABxsr9v29s9bYAHSfad5Vwi9b3vQAnG9f3dtDX0g89YO2Kj-hFSUKp4PdSBddpObFAZgzGGYQ0cHFFT4GTuZJeOf5PrFdW8SeimbTZtJTaeoAGXBiVrVBG3rH-IQcFwPBdfgBRsIKbUBaBwZDpIKq6RAjNq7SZgGR80BVW0_W0OwoyU7YsxSHOpjYFkuBCGYkgjISf5m3OxlWWExSfnyApCrAyRlbY3IFDVy31RJMSoz4QA&theme=dark).

Current Result:
[Current Result Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSTf4.png)

Expected Result: Time label should be displayed under the bars only.